# Dnlib, как заменить правильно текст массива string array?

Tags: c#, dnlib

Оригинал того что должно получиться в итоге.

```
public static string[] ss = new string[]
{
    ".data", ".txt", ".sfc", ".crypt"
};
```

Что получается на выходе в итоге на данный момент сейчас у меня:

```
public static string[] ss = new string[]
{
    "\".data\", \".txt\", \".sfc\", \".crypt\""
};
```

Мне нужно из textBox заменить данные типа `.data .txt .sfc .crypt`
за место `"$DATA"` чтобы текст был со скобочками и запятыми как в начале
`".data", ".txt", ".sfc", ".crypt"` - что должно быть в итоге.

```
public static string[] ss = new string[]
{
   "$DATA"
};
```

У меня есть публичный словарь в который я помещаю данные

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> DicPairs = new Dictionary<string, string>
```

Добавляю данные в словарь из TextBox

```
string res = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Select(DicPairs["MyText"].Split(), s => $"\"{s}\""); 
// $"\"{s}\"" - чтобы между текстом были скобки и запятая типо ".data", и.т.д
DicPairs.Add("MyText", textBox1.Text);
```

Перебираю бинарный файл так:

```
foreach (TypeDef types in module.GetTypes())
{
    foreach (MethodDef m in types.Methods)
    {
        var instr = m.Body.Instructions;
        for (var i = 0; i < m.Body.Instructions.Count; i++)
        {
             // string res = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Select(DicPairs["MyText"].Split(), s => $"\"{s}\"");
             // instr[i].Operand = DicPairs["MyText"]; // Тут происходит замена на мою строку
             instr[i].Operand = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Select(DicPairs["MyText"].Split(), s => $"\"{s}\""); // Тут происходит замена на мою строку
        }
     }
 }
...
```

Но почему-то всегда когда я открываю файл в `DnSpy`, то вижу записи в виде данных строк:

```
"\".data\", \".txt\", \".sfc\", \".crypt\""
```

Подскажите как решить?

Comment: Так у вас всё впорядке. это экранирование кавычек. попробуйте просмотреть код в точке останова. просмотрите как текст и увидите, что нет ни кавычек, ни слешей, их экранирующих.
Вам даже не нужно пытаться удалить эти элементы

Comment: `".data", ".txt", ".sfc", ".crypt"` - это не строка, это четыре строки. Эти 4 строки вы заменяете на одну.

Comment: Вы не можете добавлять и удалять элементы из созданного массива. Длина уже созданного массива - константа.

Comment: @c942o, не всё в порядке, экранки не должно быть, массив должен быть именно через запятую каждый текст. Но он немного не так записывает, ладно, буду думать

Comment: Давайте по порядку. У вас есть значение в словаре. Вы его сплитаете, окавычиваете и объединяете в _одну_ строку методом string.Join. / Очевидно, нужно массив, полученный в результате Split присвоить в Operand. Не?

Comment: `instr[i].Operand = DicPairs["MyText"].Split()`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, ну, я присвоил ему `.Split()` но к сожалению на выходe получается пустая строка ""

Comment: От нас вы что хотите? Магии? С dnlib мало кто работал, поэтому не ждите, что вам дадут готовое решение (хотя может и повезти). Помогите нам помочь вам. / `instr[i].Operand` какой тип имеет? `instr[i].Operand.GetType()` - покажите нам вывод.

Comment: Заодно покажите `instr.GetType()`

Comment: Вас очень тяжело понимать. _Оригинал того что должно получиться в итоге_ - мозговыносительно. Как я понял, изначально имеется массив с одним значением `"$DATA"`? Это и есть _оригинал_. А как _результат_ вы хотите получить массив с четырьмя значениями?

Comment: Глянул ваш предыдущий вопрос с CodeDom. Избавьте нас от упоминаний WinForms, текстбоксов, листбоксов. Не важно откуда вы получили данные (из БД, файла или консоли)! Просто пишите: имеется такая-то коллекция с такими-то данными.

Comment: Вам нужно менять не _строку_ (текст). А массив! Нужно найти _массив_ (с одним значением `$DATA`) и заменить его на новый массив (с четырьмя значениями).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, "$DATA"? Это и есть оригинал. А как результат вы хотите получить массив с четырьмя значениями? 
Да! Вот именно это и более если будут значения.

Comment: Нуууууууу? Вы покажете нам `.GetType()`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я пробую вывести instr.GetType() но оно не показывает ничего пишет про nullrefence. 
В dnlib, всё куда сложнее. Я короче понял что я просто заменяю строку как не крути, а мне то надо другое. Поэтому мне нужно найти через FieldsDef  и изменить массив. Для массива байтов я знаю как изменять через Inizialize.Value = тут массив. Но как сделать для массива строк, вот это задача